# UILable above the UITableVIew, UILable can not touch, why?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

[image]

There is a UILable above the UITableVIew, the UILable and the UITableVIew are brothers, and I added GestureRecognizer to the UILable, but this gesture cannot be triggered, why?

Comment: Did you set the label's `userInteractionEnabled` property to `true`?

Comment: set userInteractionEnabled to true

Comment: @AndréSlotta, thanks for your help, I had set userInteractionEnabled to true , I guess interaction to UiLable conflict with  interaction to tableView, but I do not know why

Comment: @AneeshG, thanks for your help, I had set userInteractionEnabled to true

Comment: @mrX Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are set userInteractionEnabled is true

**In your viewDidLoad**

```
    YOUR_Label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.uilabelTapped(_:)))
    YOUR_Label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

**In your ViewController**

```
@objc func uilabelTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("UILabel Tapped")
}
```

Make sure your tableView and uilabel are child of same view

[image: Refer this image]

Hope this will help you

Comment: thanks for your help, I had set userInteractionEnabled to true , I guess interaction to UiLable conflict with  interaction to tableView, but I do not know why